# How to return True when detecting a nested list of empty lists?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, empty-list

I was trying to return the **True** value when writing the statement:
`list = [[],[],[],[]]`
`list == []`
Instead it returns **False**

My nested list consists of a variable number of empty lists.
How do I write a single statement that could apply to nested list of [1/2/3...] empty lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
all(x == [] for x in your_list)
```

to return True if all empty

```
any(x != [] for x in your_list)
```

to return True if at least on is not empty

Answer (score 1):

You could first remove all empty lists and then check if the result equals an empty list, you could do this in a single line as follows:

```
[x for x in list if x != []] == []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `all` in python to match a condition for all elements in a list. In this case the condition is if the element is an empty list or not.

```
>>> my_list = [[], [], []]
>>> all([x == [] for x in my_list])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all items in your list are lists you can use `any` directly because the truthy value of [] is False

```
list_of_lists = [[],[],[],[]]

if not any(list_of_lists):
   # all lists are empty (or list_of_lists itself is empty)
```

Various uses of `any` and `all` will allow you to check other similar conditions:

```
if any(list_of_list):
   # at least one of the list is not empty

if all(list_of_list):
   # none of the lists are empty

if not all(list_of_list):
   # at least one of the lists is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand your problem but if you want to detect an empty list or a nested list of empty list try by getting keeping only unique elements (say your list is l)

if l ==[] or list(set(l))==[[]]:

Answer (score 0):

Use any() function.

```
list = [[], [], []]
any(list)  == bool([])  # evaluates to True
```

In python, bool value of an empty list is False and any function returns False if none of the values inside the list are True.

Comment: `[0,False]`.   What happens then?

Comment: It returns False. Bool value of zero is false